# Arrendondamento com FormatFloat

Tags: delphi

Ao tentar arredondar para 4 casas decimais o valor 18,36735 por meio da função **FormatFloat**, o sistema gera o valor 18,367**3**. Como isso é possível? Ele não deveria arredondar o valor para cima, gerando 18,367**4**? Ao menos em inúmeros outros pontos do sistema a função **FormatFloat** funciona como esperado, mas nesse ponto está ocorrendo isso...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Enfim o que quero saber é: Isso é algum *bug*? É um comportamento esperado? E, como resolver essa situação?

Detalhes importantes (*interessantes*): Se o valor a ser arredondado for alterado para 18,3**8**735 a função **FormatFloat** arredondará o valor conforme é esperado, ou seja para 18,387**4**.
Uso o Delphi XE7.

Answer (score -1):

É um comportamento normal.

O arredondamento segue uma métrica, até **4** arredonda para baixo.
A partir do **5** arredondo para cima.

É um padrão, não é só em Delphi.

Comment: Exatamente, era esse comportamento que eu esperava, mas como vc pode ver na imagem e na explicação que forneci, aconteceu exatamente o oposto. Veja na imagem que a última casa decimal é **5**, porém não arredondou a penúltima casa decimal para **4**, antes manteve o **3**. Como?

Comment: Certo! Fiz um teste " edit1.Text := formatFloat('0.0000',18.36735);" Funcionou normal. Ou seja, o 3 virou 4. Provavelmente você esta confundindo virgula(,) com ponto(.).

Comment: Continuo sem entender, pois não faz sentido algum essa situação. Porém constatei que o problema ocorre quando tento arredondar um valor que vem dum *dataset*, exemplo: *FormatFloat('0.0000',CdsItens.FieldByName('VALOR').AsFloat);*

Comment: ...tem que ver a conversão de valores, os banco de dados são padronizados para os parâmetros americanos. O que normalmente substitui (,) por (.), igualmente a data. A nossa é **dd.mm.aaaa**, onde o padrão (americano) é **mm.dd.yyyy**.
Nestes casos usamos  **StringReplace**
**ex:** _string := StringReplace(valor.Text, '. ', ', ', [rfReplaceAll]);_

Comment: Eu sempre pensei que o arredondamento usado fosse o bancário (de 1.5 ou 2.5 vai para 2, demais valores não limites segue esse outro esquema)